# Why doesnt my function doesnt work onclick?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am working with wordpress and I am trying to get this form to appear when you press a button

```
<div class="head">
    <p><?php echo __('Tests pabeigts, lūdzu iesniedziet testu'); ?></p>
</div>

<script>
    function do()
    {
        <?php echo do_shortcode( '[wpforms id="1995"]' ); ?>
    }
</script>

<div class="content">
    <button onclick="do()" class="btn btn-blue" type="submit">
        <?php echo __('Iesniegt'); ?>
    </button>
</div>
```

The function `do()` is supposed to make a form appear after you press the Submit button, but it just returns results and I cant figure out why.

Comment: 2 things, 1) you should never ever mix PHP and JS together. They're executed differently and thus, can cause unexpected behaviour and 2) don't use inline-js, it's hard to maintain :) much better to use eventHandler's :)

Comment: To add to the above comment, you should start with checking the source code of your page, that probably does not look like you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you cannot display the shortcode in javascript code, for that you will need to add the form in particular div by default hidden

```
<div class="wp_form_section" style="display:none;">
<?php echo do_shortcode([wpforms id="1995"]); ?>
</div>
```

and then you will need to display the div onclick action

```
<script>
    function do()
    {
        jQuery('.wp_form_section').show();
    }
</script>
```

This might be work for you.